Move from the sbelt to the controller Can I put the data in the map and go to the page I want?
The server is currently using the Sbelt and the Spring is in use.
Move from the sbelt to the controller
Can I put the data in the map and go to the page I want?

Press the Move button on the sbelt to go to the controller

ex) funtionc clickGo(){
await Api.post('/controller/url',formData); //==>??
}


The controller uses a query to map data and move it to a specific swivel page

@RequestMapping('/controller/url',formData')
public ~~~~~ (Model model){

return (which contains the page and data to be moved)
}

Can you move your data this way?
Place the data in the controller and go to the desired page on the svelte
